# Using OWL API, given an OWLClass, how can I get <rdfs:label> of it?

Tags: semantic-web, owl

Using OWL API 3.4.9.

Given an `OWLClass` and on ontology, how can I get `<rdfs:label>` of that `OWLClass` in that ontology?

I hope to get the label in the type of `String`.

Comment: I would recommend to use 3.4.8 for the time being, because 3.4.9 has been built with an error, which means the distribution jar does not contain all needed classes. 3.4.10 will fix the issue, and should be released in January 2014

Comment: To be more precise, this is the issue tracking the problem with 3.4.9

Comment: @Ignazio, can you please double-check my answer below? It seems the `cls.getAnnotations(o, df.getRDFSLabel())` method is no longer available in 4.0.2, as of today.

Comment: The method is available in version 3.x; it has been changed to a static method in EntitySearcher in version 4.x

Comment: Thank you, I will amend my answer with both approaches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired from the [guide to the OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/owled2011_tutorial.pdf), the following code should work (not tested):

```java
//Initialise
OWLOntologyManager m = create();
OWLOntology o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(pizza_iri);
OWLDataFactory df = OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory();

//Get your class of interest
OWLClass cls = df.getOWLClass(IRI.create(pizza_iri + "#foo"));

// Get the annotations on the class that use the label property (rdfs:label)
for (OWLAnnotation annotation : cls.getAnnotations(o, df.getRDFSLabel())) {
  if (annotation.getValue() instanceof OWLLiteral) {
    OWLLiteral val = (OWLLiteral) annotation.getValue();
    // look for portuguese labels - can be skipped
      if (val.hasLang("pt")) {
        //Get your String here
        System.out.println(cls + " labelled " + val.getLiteral());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you ensure that `val.getLiteral()` returns the `pt` version of the string

Comment: You would probably need more code to check for that, here's just some pseudo-cdoe

Answer (score 5):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20784993/206428) is valid for OWLAPI version 3.x (3.4 and 3.5 versions) but not for OWL-API 4.x and newer.

To retrieve `rdfs:label` values asserted against OWL classes, try this instead:

```java
OWLClass c = ...; 
OWLOntology o = ...;
IRI cIRI = c.getIRI();
for(OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom a : ont.getAnnotationAssertionAxioms(cIRI)) {
    if(a.getProperty().isLabel()) {
        if(a.getValue() instanceof OWLLiteral) {
            OWLLiteral val = (OWLLiteral) a.getValue();
            System.out.println(c + " labelled " + val.getLiteral());
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As Ignazio has pointed out, [EntitySearcher](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Migrate-from-version-3.4-and-3.5-to-4.0) can also be used, for example:

```java
OWLClass c = ...; 
OWLOntology o = ...;
for(OWLAnnotation a : EntitySearcher.getAnnotations(c, o, factory.getRDFSLabel())) {
    OWLAnnotationValue val = a.getValue();
    if(val instanceof OWLLiteral) {
        System.out.println(c + " labelled " + ((OWLLiteral) val).getLiteral()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The getAnnotations() method is available on OWLEntity in version 3.x; it has been changed to a static method in EntitySearcher in version 4.x.

Comment: The code you show is one way to get the same result; other ways are going through EntitySearcher and using an OWLAnnotationValueVisitorEx to extract the literal value. EntitySearcher also provides a method that accepts an annotation property, so that only the label assertions would be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method I wrote to extract labels from a class.

```
private List<String> classLabels(OWLClass class){
    List<String> labels;
    labels = ontologiaOWL.annotationAssertionAxioms(class.getIRI())
            //get only the annotations with rdf Label property
            .filter(axiom -> axiom.getProperty().getIRI().getIRIString().equals(OWLRDFVocabulary.RDFS_LABEL.getIRI().getIRIString()))
            .map(axiom -> axiom.getAnnotation())
            .filter(annotation-> annotation.getValue() instanceof OWLLiteral)
            .map(annotation -> (OWLLiteral) annotation.getValue())
            .map(literal -> literal.getLiteral())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

     return labels;
}
```